Inspect SQL query generated by Pyspark
Is there any way to translate a PySpark command into SQL and inspect it? So for example, to turn:
spark.table("this_table").filter(F.col("first_col")>100).select("second_col", "third_col")

into
SELECT second_col, third_col FROM this_table WHERE first_col > 100

Back in the day, I think the R library Sparkly had something like that but I can't seem to find that function anymore.

Assuming there is no direct way to do this in PySpark, the best I could come up with is the following:
import pandas as pd
import pandas_to_sql
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

input_data = [
    (100, 2, 3),
    (200, 4, 5),
    (300, 6, 7),
]
pd_df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, ["first_col", "second_col", "third_col"]).toPandas()

table_name = "this_table"
df = pandas_to_sql.wrap_df(pd_df, table_name)
df[df["first_col"]>100][["second_col", "third_col"]].get_sql_string()

Output:
'SELECT (second_col) AS second_col, (third_col) AS third_col FROM this_table WHERE ((first_col > 100)) '

I know this is not exactly "converting" PySpark to SQL. But if you are familiar with both PySpark and Pandas - you can use it as a workaround for the time being for your use case.
The library being used is pandas_to_sql. It's not production-ready and seems like it's not being maintained actively so use it at your own will.
Apart from this, I don't think there is any straightforward way to do what you are looking for.
Otherwise, if you just want to see the physical plan and not exact SQL then you can use explain() as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    (100, 2, 3),
    (200, 4, 5),
    (300, 6, 7),
]

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["first_col", "second_col", "third_col"])
spark_df = spark_df.filter(col("first_col")>100).select("second_col", "third_col")
spark_df.explain()

Output:
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [second_col#1L, third_col#2L]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(first_col#0L) AND (first_col#0L > 100))
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[first_col#0L,second_col#1L,third_col#2L]


Now when I see it - I wonder if it's possible to parse the physical plan and generate the SQL query. Even if possible - certainly not going to be easy.

Thanks a lot! Disappointing but very good to know. I'll give the panda_to_sql library a go.
